# Ray trace a whole 2D grid from a single light source

Tags: language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, raytracing

In a 2D grid world with known boundary, there are :-

1. a light source (blue `org`)
2. walls (grey)

How to ray trace from *center* of **every** white block in the grid to *center* of `org` efficiently?
For each block, I want a single boolean - whether it is lit.

In other words, I want the determine whether `org` can see each block (for whole world) directly or not.

[image]

### **My poor solution**

Use standard ray tracing to trace each and every white block toward `org`, but its performance is very bad.   I feel that a lot of computation is redundant.

**Related** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any-angle_path_planning  : The algorithm is still for one white block - not the whole world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Line algorithms like [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) or [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) to find the pixels in the path.

1. Start from the pixel where you want to calculate whether it is lit or not.
2. Traverse through the pixels in the direction of the light.
3. If you hit the light first, then it is lit.
4. If you hit a blocked pixel, then it is dark.

The same can be used for multiple lights as well. This will be efficient, as you only calculate one line for each pixel.

Comment: It sounds reasonable and usable for me.  Just to confirm, is the accuracy of your approach less than my poor solution?

Comment: Accuracy depends on the how you want to calculate. If you are using Wu's line algorithm, then you can use the antialiasing to play with the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

First make a `std::map` containing pairs of `double`s.  This will hold the angle ranges from which *org* is visible.  Initially populate it with `[0,2*PI]`

Then, process squares in order of their distance from *org*.  For each square:

1. Use `lower_bound` to find the range that contains the angle from *org* to the center of the block, if any.  If the angle is in one of the ranges, then the block is visible.
2. If the block is grey, then remove, split, and/or adjust nearby ranges to remove the angles through which it hides the blocks behind it.

That will work in O(N log N) time, which is not bad.  Once you're comfortable with how that works, there are a bunch of optimizations you can do.  Most importantly, if you process squares in a predefined order, so that you will visit the set of ranges in order, then you can use vectors instead of a map, because you don't have to search.  That will get the runtime down to O(N).